# Dagger2 How to inject Objects unique and created once for each Activity?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm learning Dagger2 and trying to keep it simple example and isolate other features as possible as i can to understand required parts.

*Edit: When i started learning, i'm still, Dagger seems too confusing for a beginner, i was asking if you can inject same User to same Activity whenever that Activity is created. User and Activity should have 1 to 1 relationship.

1. Activity1 <- User(100) Numbers are arbitrary hashes
2. Activity2 <-User(101)
3. Activity3 <- User(102)

This is when first time Activities are created.

My question was you navigate back to Activity2 from Activity3, then if it's possible to inject User(101) again only using Dagger? You get back to Activity1 and you get User(100) not new User or Singleton object from component created inside Application.

I was thinking Dagger keeps object like a Pool does and linking Activity instances with objects hashes or keeping states or inner references about injected objects, I was asking if it's possible.*

How can i inject same instance of an object unique to an Activity, it's created when that Activity is created for the first time, and injected again when i navigate to or start that Activity using @ActivityScope? I use the snippets below to construct this example

```
public class User {

    private String name;

    private String email;

    public User() {
        name = "Unknown";
        email = "abc@xyz.com";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Scope

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ActivityScope {
}
```

Module class

```
@Module
public class UserModule {

    @ActivityScope
    @Provides
    User provideUser() {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

Component

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(modules = {UserModule.class})
public interface UserComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

    void inject(SecondActivity secondActivity);

    void inject(ThirdActivity thirdActivity);
}
```

I get component from MyApplication and inside MainActivity to test injected objects using `userComponent = DaggerUserComponent.create();`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    User user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        UserComponent daggerUserComponent =  DaggerUserComponent.create();
        daggerUserComponent.inject(this);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Main User: " + user.hashCode());


        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

This one returns different `User` every time device is rotated and it's expected behavior since new `UserComponent` is created every time.

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    User user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getUserComponent().inject(this);


        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Second User: " + user.hashCode());
    }

}
```

Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private UserComponent userComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        userComponent = DaggerUserComponent.create();
    }


    public UserComponent getUserComponent() {
        return userComponent;
    }
}
```

SecondActivity and ThirdActivity uses UserComponent from MyApplication.

My question is why don't these classes get User unique for each Activity?
They are injected with same `User`, how can i make these classes to have their own `User` even after navigation between?

Comment: Can you add the code where you create the component in your `Application` class?

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula added MyApplication class. I found that what i ask is not possible. You can't get unique User for each Activity that exist even after Activity is destroyed. I was just wondering if i restart ThirdActivity and get same instance i got last time or the one i will get next time will be the same as last with component from application class. It behaves same as `@Singleton` and return same User for ActivitySecond and ActivityThird

Answer (score 0):

I am quite confused with your question. So I am going to answer both of them.

> How can i inject same instance of an object to each activity with
>   @ActivityScope? I use the snippets below to construct this example

To inject the same instance of an object to multiple classes, you have to use the same container and scope the provider method.

> My question is why don't these classes get User unique for each
>   Activity? They are injected with same User, how can i make these
>   classes to have their own User even after navigation between?

That is because the `provideUser` is scoped with `@ActivityScope`. Since you are using the same component from your application, you will be getting the same instance of that object everytime.

To summarize, scoped means same instance for all classes using the same container. Unscoped means always a new object instance every inject.

Comment: My question was if it's possible to inject unique instances to Activity's but it's not Dagger does. For example numbers inside parentheses are has codes i wrote arbitrary , Activity1 -> User(100), Activity2 -> User(101), Activity3 -> 103. When i navigate from Activity3 to Activity1 i was asking if i still get User(100) and same for other activities... I learnt that it's not possible. If component is declared inside Application i get same User otherwise new User is created each time activity is navigated or created.

Comment: It is possible to inject different instances using a single component instance. That is what unscoped dependencies are for. Now if you want to use the same instance for a given component, then scoping is the way to go. Now if you want a scoped component (and dependency) that would inject different instances to different classes, then you have to create a component for each of them.

Comment: I know but it returns the same instance. My question was User instance created when an Activity is created and get injected to that Activity whenever that Activity created again.

Answer (score 0):

You need different components for each of your activities, then they will provide different users for each activity, and if you will keep component alive until the activity is destroyed - it will provide the same user for same activity even after a configuration change. You can achieve it by using ViewModel and destroy component in method `onCleared()`

Comment: My question was if it's possible to get same User unique to one Activity for  each time Activity is created. You navigate back to Activity and you get same one again. You go to third Activity you still get the one created first time third when Activity. I learnt that it's not possible. I start app get User(100) for ActivityMain, User(101) in ActivitySecond, and User(102) in ActivityThird. I was asking if Dagger has any method to provide this users over and over again when you navigate through these activities. Singletons but unique to Activities.

Comment: as I've said - you need a separate component for each activity, and each component will provide different user for each activity, components must have different Scope

Comment: I guess this does not result as i asked, it injects **new** User object to Activity every time onCreate() is called. What i asked is if i could get same object for same Activity. If you ever start Activity3 again you should get the instance you got the first time you started the Activity.

Comment: and you will get the same object until component lives, just don't destroy component when activity gets destroyed, and each component will provide the same User each time

Answer (score 0):

In the `MyApplication` you create an instance of `UserComponent` and you use that to inject the `User` in the `SecondActivity` class. But in `MainActivity` class you are recreating the `UserComponent` that is why you have different instances of `User` in each activity.

You need to use 
`((MyApplication) getApplication()).getUserComponent().inject(this);`

in `MainActivity` as well.